# Loop Removes Zero Before Integer

Tags: php

If my loop runs 3 times, then the output is `0001,2,3`, but I need

```
0001
0002
0003
```

How do I get this output?

```
$i='0001';
foreach($test as $rows){
    echo $i; 
    echo '<br/>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Start with `$i = 1`, **then** you can add the leading zeros when you want display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
$i = "0001";
for($j=0;$j<1000;$j++) {
  echo str_pad($i++, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` with a *padding specifier*, e.g.:

```
$test = range(1,11);

$i = 0;
foreach ($test as $rows) {
  printf("%04d<br/>\n", ++$i);
}
```

*Output*

```
0001<br/>
0002<br/>
0003<br/>
0004<br/>
0005<br/>
0006<br/>
0007<br/>
0008<br/>
0009<br/>
0010<br/>
0011<br/>
```

In this example, `04` is a padding specifier meaning that the number (`d`) is padded with maximum 4 zeroes.

Comment: As good as it gets, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a little bit,

```
$i = "1";
$y = "000"; //Added this

while ($i < 4){
    echo $y . $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Basically you echo the 000 in front of the number each time.

Comment: well.. if the loop runs more than 9 times the outcome will become something like '00010' which is probably not what OP wants. Ruslans answer is probably better suited for OPs needs.
edit: well i just realized Ruslans answer will output 00010 as well. (edit2: not after his edit)

Comment: if ($i >= 10){Do something}.  But u'r probably right :)

Comment: Not a great solution.

Comment: True, but it is one. Ruslans answer is best i think.